# How to query by subchilds of children in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the first question that I post at Stackoverflow, because it's the first time that I don't find here a solution for my problem.

I had a Firebase database structure like this:

```
{ "races" : {
    567 : {
        "distance" : 10 ,
        "date" : 1594124321 ,
        "runners" : {
            1 : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ,
            2 : "gf76dsgf45dsag7" ,
            3 : "6f4565dsa4fa6s5" ,
            4 : "lh43k2l3kj2l4kj" ,
            5 : "lklk3f4545s7c93"
        }

    },
    568 : {
        "distance" : 5 ,
        "date" : 1594135432 ,
        "runners" : {
            1 : "faskj432lk5465f" ,
            2 : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ,
            3 : "6f4565fdsgds6s5" ,
            4 : "lh43gfdsaj2l4kj"
        }

    },
    569 : {
        "distance" : 15 ,
        "date" : 1594138245 ,
        "runners" : {
            1 : "kjhkj435kkjhkjh" ,
            2 : "gkl5lj4325dsag7" ,
            3 : "6ffsdaadsgds6s5"
        }

    },
}
```

And what I need is to do a query for get the race id's of the races where a certain runner participate.

Example: search for the runner "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", and get in this case the races 567 and 568. For doing this, `orderByChild` it's not enought, cause I'm searching by a second level subchild.

Comment: Hi. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the your database model. Use a `map` instead of a `list`:

```
569 : {
    "distance" : 15 ,
    "date" : 1594138245 ,
    "runners" : {
        "kjhkj435kkjhkjh" : true ,
        "gkl5lj4325dsag7" : true ,
        "6ffsdaadsgds6s5" : true
    }

}
```

Please check the
[Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Then, you can use a `Query` and the `orderByChild` method like this:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("races")
                  .orderByChild("runners/" + userId).equalTo(true);
```

Finally, you can add a `ValueEventListener` and obtain a list with your races.

Comment: Good answer Victor. But this will require adding an index for every runner, which is bound to become a maintenance problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value for a more scalable solution, with yet another way of modeling the data. :-)